# Entity Framework: Context Not Ready In Time for Request at Seemingly Random Times, Production Environment Only

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, datacontext, production-environment

Just yesterday I finally published the ASP.NET application I've been working on to the web.  Imported the database tables and data, changed the connection string in my web.config, all that good stuff.  The odd part is that on this production server, at seemingly random times, pages will fail to load because of server errors.  You can see for yourself:

http://world-8.net/

Try navigating to something like the [About Us](http://world-8.net/about-us/) page, or any other podcast than the first one listed.  You'll probably encounter a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  Which is weird, because the line of code being reference in the error is in a partial view used in Site.Master on every page of the site (it's when trying to retrieve information about the most recent podcast episode).  I've yet to experience this error while simply visiting pages controlled by the HomeController.  Anything controlled by the ArticleController or AdminController likes to blow up on first view.  Things tend to go smoothly for a while after visiting the first podcast on the list (http://world-8.net/podcast/world-8-50c--pax-2012-part-3/52/) before trying to navigate anywhere else.  But this is only temporary.

In my model structure, Podcasts and Articles have a 1-to-1 relationship.  Article has a PodcastId property, but this is not a FK because not every article is about a podcast.  I just need info about the Podcast object when displaying info about the article.

It's almost as if the data context is trying to "catch up" to the model creation process and doesn't make it in time for the request to finish processing.  I never saw this specific error myself, but a user of the site was kind enough to show me what he saw on his end: http://t.co/hjHcyqxt

```
The context cannot be used while the model is being created.
```

Really perplexing behavior to me; I never encountered this issue in the development environment.  And it's inconsistent nature makes it hard for me to pinpoint the issue.

If there's anyone out there more well-versed in EntityFramework that can shed some light on this, I'd much appreciate it!

Some code samples that hopefully help:

In my Models namespace:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ArticleType { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public int PodcastId { get; set; }
    public Podcast ArticlePodcast { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArticleComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Podcast
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MP3path { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PodcastTimestamp> Timestamps { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PodcastGuest> Guests { get; set; }
}
```

In my EntityFramework namespace (the repositories):

```
public class EF4DataContext: DbContext
{

    public EF4DataContext(string conString):base(conString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleComment> ArticleComments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Podcast> Podcasts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PodcastTimestamp> PodcastTimestamps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PodcastGuest> PodcastGuests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseRep
{
    public EF4DataContext DataContext { get; set; }
    public ObjectContext ObjectContext { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleRepository : BaseRep
{
    public ArticleRepository()
    {
        DataContext = new EF4DataContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionInfo"]);

        ObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DataContext).ObjectContext;
    }
}

public Article GetMostRecentPodcastArticle()
    {
        var art = DataContext.Articles.Where(a => a.ArticleType.Equals("Podcast")).OrderByDescending(a => a.PublishDate).FirstOrDefault();
        art.Comments = GetArticleCommentsByArticleId(art.Id);

        return art;
    }
```

And in my Controllers namespace:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public static PodcastRepository _podcastRepository = new PodcastRepository();
    public static ArticleRepository _articleRepository = new ArticleRepository();
    public static UserRepository _userRepository = new UserRepository();

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewData["MostRecentEpisode"] = _articleRepository.GetMostRecentPodcastArticle();
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

[HandleError]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pageNumber = 0;
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["p"]))
        {
            pageNumber = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["p"]);
        }
        var category = Request.QueryString["category"] ?? "";

        ViewData["Articles"] = _articleRepository.GetOnePageOfArticles(pageNumber, category);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["category"]))
        {
            ViewData["TotalArticleCount"] = _articleRepository.GetArticlesByType(category).Count();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["TotalArticleCount"] = _articleRepository.GetAllArticles().Count();
        }

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AboutUs()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class ArticleController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Article(int aId)
    {
        ViewData.Model = _articleRepository.GetArticleById(aId);

        return View();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** My Application_Start() method in my Global.asax.cs, at MilkyWayJoe's request

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Database.SetInitializer<EF4DataContext>(null);
    }
```

Comment: Just a thought.. do you have any kind of *seeding* going on on your global.asax.cs or at the context class?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Afraid I'm not familiar with the definition of "seeding" in this context.  But I've gone ahead and posted my Application_Start() method in Global.asax.cs if there's anything there that's relevant.

Comment: I was just wondering, cause the title of the question made me think that EF was cleaning your data and recreating it as if if you had some setting to destroy the database and seed it with test data somewhere.. like I said, just a thought..

Comment: I've seen this answer somewhere else and maybe you could try that: (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetentityframework/thread/18c993be-c357-4c99-908e-f879f28c5ee0)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: I gave it a shot, added the line "DataContext.Database.Initialize(force: false);" right after setting the DataContext in each of my controllers.  It hasn't seemed to affect anything. :(

Comment: Sorry bro.. *no more thoughts* :( I'll follow this question cause it's something I'm afraid I'll have to deal with sooner or later

Comment: Nope :( I'm starting to think it has something to do with the ASP.NET FormsAuthentication, because I also can't seem to keep a user logged in for more than ~10 seconds in production.  Maybe it's trying to validate the session and the session or session id isn't persisting?